# Let $f$ be a real function and $a<b<c<d$. If $f$ is convex on $[a,c]$ and $[b,d]$, then can we say $f$ is convex on $[a,d]$?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f$ be a real function and $a<b<c<d$. If $f$ is convex on $[a,c]$ and $[b,d]$, then can we say $f$ is convex on $[a,d]$?

Below is my attempt. If we can show that when $x_1\in[a,b]$, $x_2\in [c,d]$,

then $$f(\theta x_1+(1-\theta)x_2)\le \theta f(x_1)+(1-\theta)f(x_2),\forall \theta\in(0,1)$$ the proof is done.

Let $x_3:=\theta x_1+(1-\theta)x_2$. It is equivalent to prove
$$\frac{f(x_3)-f(x_1)}{x_3-x_1}\le \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_3)}{x_2-x_3}.$$
When $x_3\in (b,c)$, we have
$$\frac{f(x_3)-f(x_1)}{x_3-x_1}\le \frac{f(c)-f(x_3)}{c-x_3}\le \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_3)}{x_2-x_3}.$$
However, when $x_3\in [a,b]\cup [c,d]$, the approach fails.

Comment: Right, the approach fails, because that slope can't be compared to any slope in any of the subintervals. It seems that we may need to use local conditions of convex functions here, rather than global conditions.

Comment: For example, see proposition 3.2.3 in this document : https://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Anatoli.Iouditski/cours/convex/chapitre_3.pdf

Comment: Oh,Thank you.@TeresaLisbon.If we can get a straightforward proof ,it will be better.

Comment: See, the problem comes down to this : can I express , for $x_1 \in [a,b]$ and $x_2 \in [c,d]$, the ratio $\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$ in terms of quantities that are just depending on points only in $[a,c]$ or only in $[b,d]$? If you can get this you are in good shape.

Comment: Oh,thank you! I get it.

Comment: Thinking in this direction for some time. If I get an answer, I'll write it, but if you get some ideas, keep updating the post. I like the answer below, but as I mentioned it uses monotonicity of local properties , which emphasises what I said above. I am looking, as you may want, for a more elementary proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an elementary proof.

For any $p,q\in[a,d]$, denote by $L\left(p,q\right)$ the line segment joining $(p,f(p))$ and $(q,f(q))$. We shall prove that $(r,f(r))$ lies on or below $L(p,q)$ whenever $a\le p<r<q\le d$.

If $[p,q]\subseteq[b,d]$ or $[a,c]$, we are done because $f$ is convex on $[b,d]$ and $[a,c]$.

Suppose $p<b<c<q$. By replacing $f$ by $f(x)-\left[f(p)+\frac{f(q)-f(p)}{q-p}(x-p)\right]$, we may assume that $f(p)=f(q)=0$. If $(r,f(r))$ lies *above* $L(p,q,f)$, then $f(r)>0$. We will show that this leads to contradictions. There are three possibilities:

1. $r\in[b,c]$. Since $f$ is convex on $[b,c]$, $(r,f(r))$ lies on or below $L(b,c)$. Therefore $\max\{f(b),f(c)\}\ge f(r)$. Assume that $f(b)\ge f(r)$ (the other case can be treated similarly). Then $f(b)\ge f(r)>0=f(p)$. Since $p<b\le r$, the point $(b,f(b))$ lies above $L(p,r)$, but this is a contradiction because $f$ is convex on $[a,c]\supseteq[p,r]\ni b$.
2. $r\in(p,b)$. Since $p<r<b<c<q$ and $f$ is convex on $[a,c]$, we have $\frac{f(c)-f(b)}{c-b}\ge\frac{f(b)-f(p)}{b-p}\ge\frac{f(r)-f(p)}{r-p}>0$ and hence $f(c)>f(b)>0$. But then $(c,f(c))$ lies above $L(b,q)$, which is a contradiction because $f$ is convex on $[b,d]\supseteq[b,q]\ni c$.
3. $r\in(c,q)$. This is similar to case 2.

Comment: I've made an edit to explain why $(f(b)-f(p))/(b-p)>0$ in case 2. Please feel free to roll back if I've misunderstood your arguments.

Comment: Your proof is great! However,it's deserved to point out that when $b=c$, the proposition is false.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is YES. $f$ has right-hand (as well as left-hand) derivative at every point of $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$ and $f'(t+)$ is increasing in each of these intervals. This implies that $f'(t+)$ is increasing in $(a,d)$. It follows also that $f(y)=f(x)+\int_x^{y}f'(t+)dt$ for $x <y$.  This is enough to say that $f$ is convex on $(a,d)$. Convexity on the closed interval $[a,d]$ is now easy to check.

Comment: Thank you! It's great! The approach used some measure theory.

Comment: I am just curious: Is there a simple argument that  $f(y)=f(x)+\int_x^{y}f'_{\pm}(t)dt$ holds for the one-sided derivatives of a convex function or does that require more justification?

Comment: @MartinR Convex functions are locally Lipschitz . Hence $f(y)=f(x)+\int f'(t)dt$ a.e. and $f'(t+)=f'(t)=f'(t)$ at all but at most countably many points.

Comment: I see. $f$ is Lipschitz and therefore absolutely continuous on each compact interval. Thanks!